# Using Function Pointer in Java for a Simple Command Line Interpreter

Tags: java, function, pointers, interface, command-line-interface

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to build a simple cli that executes some commands. In the verification part I need to make something like a function pointer in C but I can't seem to get it right in Java using interfaces.

```
class Com{
    int argsCount;
    //pointer to function
    public Com (int argCount)
    {
        this.argsCount=argCount;
    }
}

Map <String,Com> verMap= new HashMap<String,Com>(); 

verMap.put("clear", *here*);

interface clearConsoleFunction {
    public String clearConsole();
}
```

The body of the clearConsoleFunction function should do this:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

All I need is to call clearConsole in *here* part from the map, that's why I'm trying to use interfaces because I don't know how else it can be done, and I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: `clearConsoleFunction ` is an interface . why do you want to put it into the `Map`

Comment: I don't. I'm trying to use function pointers in Java by using interfaces. But I don't know how to call them from there. I need a pointer that points to clearConsole in the map.

Comment: You are executing a command but java don't know where to execute that command. As I have seen some question related to this I found that each time the new command is fired on new instance of command prompt, you may need some wrapper classes or dll which directly interacts with command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use interfaces as a function pointer replacement you have to implement a single interface not an interface per command.

If you don't want to create a class for each command you can use an anonymous class

```
package com.me;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Map<String, CommandRunner> verMap = new HashMap<String, CommandRunner>();

        // Add all the commands :
        verMap.put("clear", new CommandRunner() {
            @Override
            public String run() {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } 
                return "";
            }
        });

        // Run it
        verMap.get("clear").run();
    }
}
```

And the CommandRunner interface :

```
package com.me;

public interface CommandRunner {
    String run();
}
```

Comment: @dili: sorry missing bracket, fixed.

Comment: CommandRunner cannot be resolved as a type.
and in the interface this error:
"The member interface CommandRunner can only be defined inside a top-level class or interface"

Comment: Create a file CommandRunner.java with the interface declaration in it.